# Ng-repeat unexpected multiple repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I have an object that looks like this:

[image]

So basically I don't know the length of the object and I'm using the following code to render the result:

```
<table style="width: 100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr ng-repeat-start="(key, item) in items() track by key" ng-if="item.primary"></tr>
        <td first someprop="2">first</td> 
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="!item.primary">
        <td>[NOT] first</tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want the first element in the table(it's also highlighted) to always be the object with the `primary=true` property.

**Expected result with the object represented above:**

[image]

**Current result:**

[image]

If I add a third element to the object, I'm getting:

[image]

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/UuzZT/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a simple semantic error in your HTML, specifically the `ng-repeat-start` element does not wrap the `<td>` so the `<td>` shows up each time even though the `ng-if` is there.  Corrected here:

http://jsfiddle.net/UuzZT/1/

*However*, there are other problems stemming from the fact that you are trying to iterate over an object; objects do not have ordinal properties.

Comment: Any suggestions how the object with `primary=true` be always first?

Comment: I switched to array instead of object and with some changed I fixed my issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your first table row does not include the table data (td outside tr)

Change your code to this:

```
<table style="width: 100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr ng-repeat-start="(key, item) in items() track by key" ng-if="item.primary">
    <td first someprop="2">first</td>
</tr> 
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="!item.primary">
    <td>[NOT] first</tr>
</tr>
```